# Can I use Google Android Maps with Threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, maps

I tried to call my map.java (Google Android Maps class) with save.java class at the same time, but I can't call onCreate function (or which class call the map). I need an example. How can I call maps class and another class at the same time with threads? I call exec.java first.

exec.java

```
public class exec{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThMap rc = new ThMap();
        Thread th0 = new Thread(rc);
        th0.start();

    }

}
```

ThMap.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ThMap extends Activity implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Map.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: You don't call classes, you call methods.  If you mean how do you start two activities at the same time, I'm pretty sure you can't.  What is your goal here, at a higher level?  What do you want the app to do?

Comment: I try to access mysql and insert some values. but when i tried this my app. crushes because it insersect onlocationchange function so that i think i should use threads